# running make on a http_deamon swi prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

If I run a website using a http_deamon on a server is it possible to ssh into the server then open the prolog interface, run some queries, notably make and close the interface with the website still running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible to reload definitions with a running HTTP server.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a `screen` or `tmux` session. This lets you detach the terminal to log in later into the same session.
2. Start the server. With the HTTP daemon library, use the `--interactive` flag to get an interactive **toplevel**.
3. Detach the session.
4. Log out.

At any later time, to reload definitions while the server is still running, simply:

1. log in again
2. re-attach the session
3. run `?- make.` as usual.

**Caveat**: With the HTTP **Unix daemon**, `make/0` currently some issues, but you can always start an HTTP server also without using the `http_unix_daemon` library, and in that case `make/0` works more nicely.

An alternative is to simply provide a special URL handler that runs `make/0` within the server when that URL is accessed. Again, it may not work smoothly with the Unix daemon library, but typically when run without it.